# Passing an element of an array of structs in C

Tags: c, function, struct, parameter-passing, argument-passing

I was trying to pass one of the 20 "database" structs I made

here is my prototype for the function "add"

```
void add(struct database test);
```

I want to pass my database struct and for now i'll just call it "test"

Here is my database structure

```
struct database
{
    char ID[6];
    char Duration[3];
};

main()
{

   char menu;
   struct database employee[20]; // I make 20 employee variables
   int a = 0;                    /*A counter I use to edit certain structs 
                                   ie a=2  "employee[a]" = "employee[2]" */
```

I then call the function like this:

```
add(employee[a]);
a++;  /*Once it exits this I want it to go to the next employee
       variable so I increment the counter */
```

The actual function looks like this:

```
void add(struct database test)
{
    static int a = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter a 5 digit employee number: ");
    scanf("%s", test[a].ID);

    a++
}
```

while doing this I get the error:

Error E2094 Assignment.c 64: 'operator+' not implemented in type 'database' for arguments of type 'int' in function add(database)

It says the error is at

```
scanf("%s", test[a].ID);
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and I apolgise if I have formatted this wrong, still learning for to use stack overflow, so sorry!

Comment: why cant you pass struct pointer as **void add(struct database *test);**, change add(employee[a]); to **add(&employee[a]);** and scanf("%s", test[a].ID); to **scanf("%s", test->ID);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do in order to get it right:

```
void add(struct database* test)
{
    printf("\nPlease enter a 5 digit employee number: ");
    scanf("%s",test->ID);
}

int main()
{
    ...
    int a;
    struct database employee[20];
    for (a=0; a<sizeof(employee)/sizeof(*employee); a++)
        add(&employee[a]); // or add(employee+a);
    ...
}
```

Comment: For the next person who see this: Make note of the & in the call to add(). Easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

`add(struct database test)` declares a `struct database` as parameter. This is not an array, so you cannot index it.

So

```
test[a]
```

is invalid.

---

Also the `int a` inside `add()` is different from the `int a` defined in `main()`. Inside `add()` the latter `a` is hidden by the former `a`.

---

Also^2 you are passing to `add()` a copy of the array's element declared in `main()`. So any modifications done to `test` in side `add()` are lost when returning from `add()`. They won't be visible in the array declated in `main()`.